# How to use systemjs to load CDN module but exclude them in Browserify

Tags: jquery, cdn, browserify, systemjs

I want to take advantage of nodejs to develop the front-end part of a legacy website (The backend stays in PHP). Traditionally, the `index.html` will load

- `jquery` from a CDN
- some third-party library from other CDN.
- some application scripts
- If the third-party library depends on `jquery` then it is loaded after `jquery`

**index.html** example:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn/thirdparty.depend.onjquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/i18next/i18next.min.js"></script>

<script src="customer.js"></script>
<script src="profile.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

1) I want to use `systemjs` to load `jquery` from CDN:

```
System.config({
    "main": "main",
    "map": {
        "jquery": "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js",
    }
});
```

2) I want to bundle all the **applicatif** scripts (excluding the scripts from CDN) to one file + uglify them with `browserify` / `gulp`

Question

1) How can I configure `system.js` so that it load third-party library in the right order as in `index.html`: i.e 
`jquery` must to be loaded before `thirdparty.depend.onjquery.js`

2) How to bundle all the applicatif scripts (`customer.js`, `profile.js`, `main.js`) which `require('thirdparty.depend.onjquery.js')` from CDN.

I think that the use case is quiet standard but I did not find any example project.

Answer (score 0):

As of I believe System.js v0.17.0 (currently 0.19.6) you would use the meta: {} configuration to establish these dependencies.

@see [this](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/0.17.0/docs/config-api.md#meta)